# How to test if file exists on an SDCard?

Tags: android, pdf, input, copy

I'm trying to copy a PDF file from my app's private storage to sd card so other PDF programs can open it. My  problem is to test if the file exist. If the test file.exists() is true I will not copy the file again. The problem is when the condition is true, android show me a message that my file is not a valid PDF file

```
private void CopyReadAssets()
{
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();

    InputStream in = null;
    OutputStream out = null;
    File file = new File(getFilesDir(), "ac8.pdf");

    try {
        in = assetManager.open("ac8.pdf");
        out = openFileOutput(file.getName(), Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

        if (file.exists()) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File already exist", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            copyFile(in, out);
            in.close();
            in = null;
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            out = null;
        }
    } catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());               
    }

    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(
                Uri.parse("file://" + getFilesDir() + "/ac8.pdf"),
                "application/pdf");

        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No PDF application found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int read;
    while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1)
    {
        out.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Third-party apps have no access to your app's [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) (e.g., `getFilesDir()` directory). Either:

- Write the file to [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html), or
- Leave the file on internal storage, but then [use `FileProvider`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) to serve the file via a `content://` `Uri` to the third-party PDF viewer

You can read more about the second approach in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/index.html).

Comment: Thank's for your help